# Materialize navbar-fixed sidenav works on the initial click, but after that first click, it will not appear again

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I have implemented the `sidenav` as directed in the Materialize documentation, and it works on the initial click, but after that first click, it will not appear again. Has anyone faced this problem before? I have been Googling for 2 days now and can't seem to find a solution. Here is my code and any help towards helping me learn is very much appreciated:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav>
    <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="<%= root_path %>" class="brand-logo left-align">My Thing</a>
      <ul id="nav_desktop" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <% if current_page?("/")%>
         <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
        <% else %>
         <li><a href="<%= root_path%>#products">Products</a></li>
        <% end %>
        <li><a href="/company">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="/careers">Careers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
  <% if current_page?("/")%>
  <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
  <% else %>
  <li><a href="<%= root_path%>#products">Products</a></li>
  <% end %>
  <li><a href="/company">Company</a></li>
  <li><a href="/careers">Careers</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav({draggable:true, closeOnClick:true});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried moving the `ul` into the `navbar-fixed` `div` but then the screen turns grey and I am unable to access the links in the `sidenav` at all. Is this just an issue with Materialize, I am seeing it is a problem in quite a few forums.

Comment: This has been happening to me too.